# How to append values to a cookie instead of overriding the existent values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example for the following cookie:

```
Cookie name: favAnimal
Existent value: donkey
```

I want to append this value:

```
tiger
```

without deleting donkey. How to do that? I know I can read the current cookie value, add tiger to that and set the new string as the new cookie value but was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: `I can read the current cookie value, add tiger to that and set the new string as the new cookie value` is your answer

Comment: No there is no better way. You need to rewrite the cookie with the appended value. You can use delimiters to separate the values

Comment: If you found your solution, add it as an answer and accept.